# Please help me with this cone question.

Tags: geometry

I really need help with this cone question.

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm2Yb.png)

For this problem, I know that the answer is 3 times 2 to the 3rd root. However, I am not sure on this.

Could you please show me how to do with using algebra/geometry?

Please help, and thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the volume ratio of similar shapes is $\frac{1}{4}$, then the length ratio will be $\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{4}}$.

$6\cdot \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{4}} = 3.77976$